# CSS display text with formatted line-height

Tags: html, css

I want to show text file in browser with line-break. This is my code:

```css
.readable {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:32px;
    font-family: league-gothic,sans-serif; 
    text-align:left; 
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: pre-line;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

With word-break and white-space attribute, it can show break-line normally. However I want to stretch paragraph's line-height property. Example replacing \n with \n\n.
I dont want use javascript. Is there anyway that just use css only ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with increasing the line-height value?

Comment: show a minimal example and some evidence of trying to find a solution

Comment: I capture a screenshot at: http://s10.postimg.org/dxw9dnf3t/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:first-line` attribute to increase the space between paragraphs. For example:

```css
.readable::first-line {
    line-height: 300%;
}
```